# Calculating linear acceleration from wheel torque

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

Excuse me if this is trivial to answer as I don't have much background in mechanics yet.

Suppose we have a bicycle we want to accelerate, the bicycle can be modeled as two wheels which do not slip with fixed rotational inertias connected by a rod with a specific mass.

How do we

1. calculate the acceleration of the bicycle from a constant torque being applied?
2. calculate the needed torque to follow a particular acceleration pattern?

I'm actually interested in cars but it's better to start with the simplest case. I'm confused on how to relate torque with linear acceleration.

You can model the part of the wheel touching the ground as a lever pushing against the mass and you can model the wheel being rotated around its axle but I dont know how to combine the acceleration of the mass of the rod linearly with the acceleration of the wheel rotationally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, recognize the kinematic relationship between bike speed $v$ and wheel rotation $\omega$

$$ v = \omega R \tag{1}$$

Then take the derivative of the above in terms of accelerations

$$ a = \dot{\omega} R \tag{2}$$

Now separate the bike body and the driving wheel and put a connection force $F$ between them. Write down the equations of motion for the two parts

[image: fig1]

$$ \left. \begin{aligned}
  F & = m_{\rm body} a \\
  \sum \tau_{\rm wheel}  & = I_{\rm wheel} \dot{\omega} \\
\end{aligned} \right\} \begin{aligned} F & = m_{\rm body} a \\  \tau - R\, F & = I_{\rm wheel} \frac{a}{R} \end{aligned}$$

**Solve the above two equations for the acceleration $a$ and force $F$** to get your results.

The above ignores the mass of the wheel as a simplification. To include the mass of the wheel then you have a tractive force from the ground that is slightly more than the body reaction $F$.

[image: fig2]

$$ \begin{aligned} F & = m_{\rm body} a \\  F_{\rm tract} - F & = m_{\rm wheel} a \\  \tau - R\, F_{\rm tract} & = I_{\rm wheel} \frac{a}{R} \end{aligned}$$

To be solved in terms of $F$, $F_{\rm tractive}$ and $a$.

It is interesting to form the effective mass $m_{\rm eff}$ such that

$$ \frac{\tau}{R} = m_{\rm eff} a $$

and see what goes into it, and how the MMOI of the wheel affects it.

Comment: Thanks, could you explain the second equation in more detail? I don't understand $F_{tract}-F=M_{wheel}a$

Comment: Nevermind, I see is is the linear acceleration of the wheel. Thank you.

Comment: Ah one more thing, why isn't exactly $F_{tract}=F$? You say the tractive force is slightly more, could you explain why?

Comment: @FourierFlux - the force difference between the two goes into accelerating the wheel. Put it a different way $$ F_{\rm tract} = m_{\rm wheel} a + m_{\rm body} a $$ and $$ F = m_{\rm body} a $$

Comment: I see, you have to have a force differential for the acceleration. Thanks so much.