Calculating vehicle and tire acceleration with tire slipping
I'm attempting to simulate the motion of a vehicle with $N$ tires and I'm running into some trouble deriving forces/acceleration when adding friction and tire slipping into the picture. Here's an image of the model I'm using:

Variables include:

$M_v$ - the total mass of the vehicle
$R_{i}$ - the radius of the $i$th tire
$I_{i}$ - the moment of inertia of the $i$th tire
$T_{i}$ - the torque applied to each tire (from the brakes and engine)
$N_{i}$ - the normal force of the $i$th tire on the ground
$F_{si}$ - static friction coefficient of the $i$th tire against the ground
$F_{ki}$ - kinetic friction coefficient of the $i$th tire against the ground
$a_v$ - the linear acceleration of the vehicle
$\alpha_i$ - the angular acceleration of the $i$th tire

The goal is the calculate the angular acceleration of each tire and the linear acceleration of the vehicle as a whole. Without tire slipping, here is my solution:
Because the tires aren't slipping, we assume that all ground forces involved are under the static friction force threshold $\mu_s N_i$. Therefore, $F_{si} = -T_i / R_i$ for all tires.
The total force exerted on the system must be distributed across the vehicle and tire accelerations (the normal force cancels out trivially so I'm excluding that):
$a_v M_v + \sum{\frac{\alpha_i I_i}{R_i}} = \sum{F_{si}}$
(Sub-question: is $\frac{\alpha_i I_i}{R_i}$ the correct way to go from angular acceleration to force at a given radius? I tried doing these calculations using force directly, rather than acceleration, and got a result that was off by $1/R_i$ for this term. I couldn't find the source of the discrepancy so I suspect I have some misconception of the relationship between torque and force.)
$a_v = (\sum{F_{si}} - \sum{\frac{\alpha_i I_i}{R_i}}) / M_v$
Each tire contact point must be accelerating at the same rate as the vehicle (otherwise, the tires would slip):
$\alpha_i R_i = a_v$
$\alpha_i = a_v / R_i$
Therefore, we can substitute this back into the previous equation to get:
$a_v = (\sum{F_{si}} - \sum{\frac{a_v I_i}{R_i^2}}) / M_v$
Rearranging, we solve for $a_v$:
$a_v = \frac{\sum{F_{si}}}{M_v + \sum{I_i / R_i^2}}$
Since $F_{si} = -T_i / R_i$, this becomes
$a_v = \frac{-\sum{T_i / R_i}}{M_v + \sum{I_i / R_i^2}}$
(As mentioned above, it's possible that the $R_i^2$ term should be $R_i$ but I haven't yet figured out whether I'm doing something wrong here or in my other derivation.)
Now I'm trying to introduce tire slipping. This means that, for tires that are slipping, $F_{si}$ will be replaced with $F_{ki}$. The problem is that I can no longer assume that $\alpha_i R_i = a_v$ because the contact points of the slipping tires will be accelerating at different rates than the vehicle's linear motion. Essentially, I'm trying to solve for $N+1$ variables (vehicle acceleration and tire acceleration), so I need $N+1$ equations relating these variables somehow and for the non-slipping case, the acceleration equality provided these. Is there perhaps some obvious equality I should be using here that I'm overlooking?

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/819958/forces-accelerating-a-tire

Using Free Body Diagram for this analysis, you will find that the sum of the frictional forces is used only for the vehicle acceleration. The wheel rotational acceleration shouldn't be included.

Thank you! I believe I have come up with the solution and that was the key. The piece that clarified it for me was the answer to this post, which separates out the wheels from the rest of the vehicle: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/672375/calculating-linear-acceleration-from-wheel-torque My previous attempts at FBDs weren't doing that. I'll post my solution in a bit.

I believe I've come up with the solution. What helped was separating out the wheels from the rest of the vehicle rather than treating them all as one in the FBD. Specifically, the tires are exerting linear force on the axle. The answer to this post is what helped: Calculating linear acceleration from wheel torque
Here's my solution in code-style syntax with comments. If it would be helpful to anybody I can rewrite it in math syntax.
Consider a vehicle with N tires touching the ground. There is a linear force being exerted on the vehicle and torque being exerted on each tire. This
function calculates how much force is actually applied to each portion of the vehicle. Some of the tires may be slipping.

Each tire is being powered by tireTorque{i}. The tire exerts tireAxleForce{i} on the vehicle via the axle. A frictional force (tireFrictionForce{i})
from the ground is exerted on the tire's contact point. For tires which are slipping, this force is simply equal to the kinetic friction force. For
tires which are not slipping, this force is equal to the static friction force and must be calculated.

We'll use the notation SUM to be a sum over all tires, SUM_N to be a sum over all non-slipping tires, and SUM_S ton be a sum over all slipping tires.

We start with the following equalities:

vehicleMassWithoutTires * vehicleAcceleration = vehicleForce + SUM(tireAxleForce{i})
tireFrictionForce{i} - tireAxleForce{i} = tireMass{i} * vehicleAcceleration
tireTorque{i} - tireFrictionForce{i} * tireRadius{i} = tireMomentOfInertia{i} * vehicleAcceleration / tireRadius{i}

For non-slipping tires, tireTorque{i} is a provided input and tireFrictionForce{i} is unknown. For slipping tires, tireFrictionForce{i} is known (it
is equal to the kinetic friction force) and tireTorque{i} refers to the amount of non-slip torque corresponding to tireFrictionForce{i} (the
remaining torque causes angular acceleration with no contribution to the vehicle's linear acceleration).

We can rearrange the last two equations to get:

tireAxleForce{i} = tireFrictionForce{i} - tireMass{i} * vehicleAcceleration
tireFrictionForce{i} = (tireTorque{i} - tireMomentOfInertia{i} * vehicleAcceleration / tireRadius{i}) / tireRadius{i}

For non-slipping tires:

tireAxleForce{i} = (tireTorque{i} - tireMomentOfInertia{i} * vehicleAcceleration / tireRadius{i}) / tireRadius{i} - tireMass{i} * vehicleAcceleration
                 = tireTorque{i} / tireRadius{i} - vehicleAcceleration * (tireMomentOfInertia{i} / tireRadius{i}^2 + tireMass{i})

Finally, we can return to our first equation and make substitutions:

vehicleMassWithoutTires * vehicleAcceleration
    = vehicleForce + SUM(tireAxleForce{i})
    = vehicleForce + SUM_N(tireAxleForce{i}) + SUM_S(tireAxleForce{i})
    = vehicleForce
      + SUM_N(tireTorque{i} / tireRadius{i} - vehicleAcceleration * (tireMomentOfInertia{i} / tireRadius{i}^2 + tireMass{i}))
      + SUM_S(tireFrictionForce{i} - tireMass{i} * vehicleAcceleration)
    = vehicleForce
      + SUM_N(tireTorque{i} / tireRadius{i}) - vehicleAcceleration * SUM_N(tireMomentOfInertia{i} / tireRadius{i}^2 + tireMass{i})
      + SUM_S(tireFrictionForce{i}) - vehicleAcceleration * SUM_S(tireMass{i})

vehicleForce + SUM_N(tireTorque{i} / tireRadius{i}) + SUM_S(tireFrictionForce{i})
    = vehicleAcceleration * vehicleMassWithoutTires
      + vehicleAcceleration * SUM_N(tireMomentOfInertia{i} / tireRadius{i}^2 + tireMass{i})
      + vehicleAcceleration * SUM_S(tireMass{i})
    = vehicleAcceleration * (vehicleMassWithoutTires + SUM_N(tireMomentOfInertia{i} / tireRadius{i}^2 + tireMass{i}) + SUM_S(tireMass{i}))
    = vehicleAcceleration * (vehicleMassWithoutTires + SUM(tireMass{i}) + SUM_N(tireMomentOfInertia{i} / tireRadius{i}^2))
    = vehicleAcceleration * (vehicleMass + SUM_N(tireMomentOfInertia{i} / tireRadius{i}^2))

vehicleAcceleration = (vehicleForce + SUM_N(tireTorque{i} / tireRadius{i}) + SUM_S(tireFrictionForce{i}))
                        / (vehicleMass + SUM_N(tireMomentOfInertia{i} / tireRadius{i}^2))

Now we can simply plug in vehicleAcceleration to obtain other values. For each non-slipping tire, we can compute tireFrictionForce{i} to see if it
exceeds the static friction force threshold (if it does, we can re-run this calculation with that tire now slipping). For each slipping tire, we can
compute tireTorque{i}, the amount of torque necessary to cause the vehicle's motion. Any excess torque is simply added as additional acceleration for
that tire.

